Why doesn’t the Axiom of Choice follow, in this scenario?

The axiom of choice was proven independent of ZF.
Here, it appears to be saying that for any relation on X and Y, there is a function with the exact same values.
Why is this
a) Not logically guaranteed? I think the axiom of replacement says the image of all definable functions exists as a set.
b) Useful?

I think I get it. If the relation is defined for an a, it may have multiple values for b, but the axiom of choice says there is a way to choose one of them so we can turn a relation into a function. However, still curious to understand this more deeply. Welcoming better explanations. Thanks

The axiom of choice is independent of ZF, not ZFC.

AR ensures if you have a definable function its image will be a set, but it does not guarantee the existence of a choice function for an arbitrary family of non-empty sets as exemplified by Russell's socks: for any collection of pairs of shoes, one can pick out the left shoe from each pair to obtain an appropriate collection of shoes...For an infinite collection of pairs of socks (assumed to have no distinguishing features), there is no obvious way to make a function...selecting one sock from each pair without invoking the axiom of choice...

Questions about math should be posted on Math Stack Exchange, I don't think this is appropriate for Philosophy SE. Asking on MSE is far more likely to get a correct answer, too.... That being said, your comment is correct: axiom of Choice is needed specifically when A assigns many values in Y to each value in X. An equivalent statement to the slide you posted is that: F is a choice function for A precisely when F is a subset of A, F is a function, and the domain of F equals the domain of A (where dom(A)={x : ∃(y∈Y), (x,y)∈A} is the definition of domain).

(cont.) In case A is a function, existence of such F is trivial by taking F=A, and in that case AoC is irrelevant. It's only when A is not a function that AoC becomes relevant, and finding F can be extremely difficult/impossible without AoC. Double Knot gives a good example with socks. Suppose that a "sock" is defined as a subset of ℝ. Can you devise a mechanism which chooses one sock from each unordered pair of socks? The deep symmetry of ℝ makes this task intractable, and ZF without C cannot produce a satisfying mechanism.

@JadeVanadium, a pair of socks as a subset of R is not a good example, because one can devise a simple mechanism for choosing one sock: namely, take the least element.

@MikhailKatz You misread what I wrote. I did not say "a pair of socks is a subset of ℝ", I explicitly said "a sock is defined as a subset of ℝ". The set {1/(n^2+1) : n∈ℕ} is a sock, and the set {1/2^n : n∈ℕ} is also a sock. Between these two socks, which of them is "the least element"?
